# Firestore batch.commit() doesn't send data to the server the first time it's called

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a React web app and I'm trying to do a batch upload to Firestore. I have an upload button that triggers the function below. The first time I click the button, I see the first message in the log, but that's it - the promise returned by batch.commit() is neither resolved nor rejected, so neither of the other console messages appears. There's nothing in the network tab.

When I click the upload button a second time, the data is uploaded and the *Done* message appears in the console. What's going on?

```
const onUploadClick = () => {
  const db = firebase.firestore()
  const batch = db.batch()

  const nycRef = db.collection('activities').doc('NYC')
  batch.set(nycRef, { name: 'New York City' })

  console.log('The batch is set to go.')

  batch
    .commit()
    .then(function() {
      console.log('Done.')
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(`There was an error: ${err}`))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by moving `const db = firebase.firestore()` to a different place where it would be executed on app startup instead of right before the upload happens. I don't see anything in the docs that says it's required to do it this way, so I opened an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2122).

Comment: Are you saying that `firebase.firestore()` seems to be lazy-and-asynchronously initialized? That shouldn't happen. It doesn't matter where you call `firebase.firestore()`. Even `const nycRef = firebase.firestore().collection('activities').doc('NYC')` should work without problems.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, it should!